# breaking the inner most for loop if conditions fails

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the below code that is a method which takes two parameter as list type as shown below in which I have to first iterate the first list and then with in that I have to iterate over the second list so code is like below

```
public void archive( List<Order> orderList , List<String> storeList)
{
  if (!storeList.isEmpty())
   for(int i=0;i<storeList.size();i++)
    {
       for(Order order :  orderList)
       {
          //I am making some rest template call here
          //if exception ocurs then break the nested  for loop for that order only so that we 
          //can pick up the next order

        }
    }
```

please advise I am making some rest template call here if exception occurs then break the nested  for loop for that order only so that we can pick up the next order please advise how to achieve the same and also that the above nested loops are the right solution please advise

Comment: What's wrong with using `break;`?

Comment: Yep, slam on the breaks!

Answer (score 1):

use `break;` in `catch`

```java
public void archive( List<Order> orderList , List<String> storeList)
{
  if (!storeList.isEmpty())
   for(int i=0;i<storeList.size();i++)
    {
       for(Order order :  orderList)
       {
            try {
              //  Block of code to try
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                 break;
            }

        }
    }
```